# Android resizable rectangle crop

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I need to crop a picture using a resizable rectangle based on user touch events. I'm doing this because the crop intent feature isn't supported by all devices, so I'm creating my own.

I have the original image as a bitmap and it's displayed on the screen as an image view.

Now what I need to do next is have a rectangle (already know size it needs to be) that can be resized and moved for the user to crop the image (Say get a face).

How can I create a resizable rectangle like this?

Comment: I've done a project like yours. First I downloaded the _whole_ Android source [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9728899/942821) (version 4.0.3_r1). Then found the source of the Gallery app and… refactored it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CropImage](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage) has worked great for me.

Comment: +1. I've found out that MMP-forTour's fork works better (doesn't cause "Out of memory exception"). 
https://github.com/MMP-forTour/cropimage/commit/ce96d819e835e84af787e278339eec7d3d52230f