# Make an adjustable cropping rectangle on bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, crop

im now doing a cropping function for my bitmap. I able to crop my bitmap using ontouch event which i randomly touch 2 points on my bitmap and create a new bitmap regarding to the coordination of the 2 touch points.

However, is there have a solution that have an adjustable rectangle that can let put on my bitmap to crop the region of interest?

Here's is my code that i mention above:

```
    image_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (x1 == -1 && y1 == -1 && x2 == -1 && y2 == -1) {
                    x1 = (int) event.getX();
                    y1 = (int) event.getY();
                } else if (x1 != -1 && y1 != -1 && x2 == -1 && y2 == -1) {
                    x2 = (int) event.getX();
                    y2 = (int) event.getY();

                    change_to_bitmap_from_array = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            change_to_bitmap_from_array, x1, y1, x2, y2);

                    image_view.setImageBitmap(change_to_bitmap_from_array);
                    // done.setEnabled(true);
                    x1 = -1;
                    y1 = -1;
                    x2 = -1;
                    y2 = -1;

                }
            }

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11335644/724514

Answer (score 0):

As I know there's no any formal solution for your problem. But you could do it by yourself, use transparent View for rectangle and RelativeLayout with absolute coords; control it's size and position on touch events