# How to crop a bitmap in image view in android and show in next it in next activity?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, crop, resize-crop

I want to crop a `bitmap` that i am setting in an image view in `Linearayout`. I am using this code. What is code to crop that `"cropimage"`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen4);
        // Screen3.crop
        ImageView cropimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropimage);
        bm = Screen3.crop;
        cropimage.setImageBitmap(bm);

 }//onCreate
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android resizable rectangle crop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335079/android-resizable-rectangle-crop)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmCache = imageView.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = null;
if (bmCache != null) {
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmCache);
}
cropimage.setImageBitmap(bm);
imageView.destroyDrawingCache();
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: its not working :(.Like no output is showing even image is not showing .

Comment: I want to crop an image on run time and then show it in next activity. Like when app runs,it display an image.I then crop it there in rectangle and then show that crop image in next activity. Can you please explain me how it possible.

Comment: You said, the image from ImageView in first activity, just getDrawingCache and clone a copy, then putExtra by intent, the second activity can get it.

Comment: You don't know what: 1. how to crop image? 2. how to deliver content between two activity? what's your point?

Comment: I want to crop image just..how can i do it? please help